# Android application that adds a string with every packet sent to the router

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi

I am looking to develop an android application where internet would work through a specific router only if a certain key in the packet matches the key on the router. How shall i attach that key to the packets being sent by any application so that those packets can pass through?

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning to create "usual" app for installing on every device then forget about that kind of application, it's **strongly** insecure for users and for this reason - impossible... it's possible only if you are working on own system version, in which you can implement whatever you want